# Работа с формами номер телефона

Tags: jquery

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на форма появлялось +7()___  и данные вписывались внутрь?

Comment: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая замечательная штука - [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#form input[name="phone"]').mask('7 (999) 999-99-99', {autoclear: false});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Чегот не работает.

Comment: не знаю почему но если у ячейки стоит type="number" маска не появляется. А если вводить цифры они стирают друг-друга

Comment: `type="number"` задает тип вводимых символов, если вы используете маску в поле попадают другие символы, типа скобок, подчерков, тире и т.д., и тут уже думаю возникает проблемка с работой плагина. В [документации](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html) плагина в примере используется тот же `type="text"`, ставить полю `type="number"` и использовать маску с ним вместе не стоит.